# Script to extract and find min, max and avg from a file using a shell script from traceroute output

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, traceroute

I am creating a shell scrip to store the output of the `traceroute` command with a user-entered input to a file.

I want to extract the latency for each packet and each router and find the min, max and average times for each packet.

If this is the output of `traceroute`:

```
1  176.221.87.1 (176.221.87.1)  1.474 ms  1.444 ms  1.390 ms
2  f126.broadband2.quicknet.se (92.43.37.126)  10.047 ms  19.868 ms  23.156 ms
3  10.5.12.1 (10.5.12.1)  24.098 ms  24.340 ms  25.311 ms
```

I need to find the max of all latency for the first packet, which is in this case `24.098 ms`. Similarly min is `1.474` and average for the first packet is `11.873 ms`. I need to do this for each packet.

I want output like:

```
1  176.221.87.1 (176.221.87.1)  1.474 ms  1.444 ms  1.390 ms
2  f126.broadband2.quicknet.se (92.43.37.126)  10.047 ms  19.868 ms  23.156 ms
3  10.5.12.1 (10.5.12.1)  24.098 ms  24.340 ms  25.311 ms
```

For the first packet:

```
Minimum: 1.474 ms
Maximum: 24.098 ms
Average: 11.873 ms

.
.
```

and so on.

I am not able to come up with an awk statement to do this. Perhaps there is another way?

Any inputs would be really helpful.

Comment: If your sample output matching data, there is a strange computation rule.  Shouldn't Max=24.098, and Average=(1.474+10.047+24.098)/3=11.873 ?

Comment: Oh, sorry I wrote wrong. Thanks for noticing.
Updated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, you want something like this

```
    NR == 1 {
            n = $4                   # set min to first value
            u = $5                   # keep time unit for later
    }

    {
            s += $4
            c++
            if ($4 > m) {            # update max
                    m = $4
            }
            if ($4 < n) {            # update min
                    n = $4
            }
    }       

    END {
            print "Minimum: " n, u "\nMaximum: " m, u "\nAverage: " s / c, u
    }
```

For all three columns, you can extend this easily

```
    NR == 1 {
            split("4,6,8",ix,",")
            for(i in ix) n[ix[i]] = $(ix[i])
            u = $5
    }

    {
            c++
            for(i in ix) {
                 p = ix[i];
                 s[p] += $(p)
                 if ($p > m[p]) m[p] = $p
                 if ($p < n[p]) n[p] = $p
            }
    }

    END {
            mins = "Minimum ("u"):"
            maxs = "Maximum ("u"):"
            avgs = "Average ("u"):"
            for(i in ix) {
                  mins = mins FS n[ix[i]]
                  maxs = maxs FS m[ix[i]]
                  avgs = avgs FS s[ix[i]]/c
            }
            print mins
            print maxs
            print avgs
    }
```

Should print

```
Minimum (ms):  1.474 1.444 1.390
Maximum (ms):  24.098 24.340 25.311
Average (ms):  11.873 15.2173 16.619
```

Comment: Thanks! So this finds the information for the first packet, how to apply it for  the 2nd and 3rd ?

Comment: Thanks that was helpful :)